# ValueError: Layer sequential_16 expects 1 input(s), but it received 8 input tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have multiple csv input and trying to test a neural network. I have 8 features in cvs's (211583x8). I got "ValueError: Layer sequential_16 expects 1 input(s), but it received 8 input tensors."  Can anyone help me to resolve this error?

```
train_dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    file_pattern = train_file_names,
    batch_size=10, num_epochs=1,
    num_parallel_reads=20,
    shuffle_buffer_size=10000)

validation_dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    file_pattern = validation_file_names,
    batch_size=10, num_epochs=1,
    num_parallel_reads=20,
    shuffle_buffer_size=10000)

test_dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    file_pattern = test_file_names,
    batch_size=10, num_epochs=1,
    num_parallel_reads=20,
    shuffle_buffer_size=10000)

model = tf.keras.Sequential()

model.add(layers.Dense(8, activation="relu",input_shape=(1, 7) ))
model.add(layers.Dense(8, activation="relu",input_shape=(1, 7)))
model.add(layers.Dense(8, activation="softmax",input_shape=(1, 7)))
model.add(layers.Dense(1))
model.summary()

model.fit(train_dataset, validation_data = validation_dataset,
         validation_steps = validation_steps, epochs = 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add input with proper input shape.

```
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(8,)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, input_shape = (1,7) , activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, input_shape = (1,7) , activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, input_shape = (1,7) , activation='softmax'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
model.output_shape
```